# My JavaScript function is not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, function, alert

For some reason this function isn't working and the alert box isn't popping up, yet my code is identical to another page that works.  Am I missing something stupid here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>What's my name?</title>
  <script>
    function whatsMyName() {
        var first = "firstname";
        var last = "lastname";
        alert("My name is"+" "first+" "+last);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick=whatsMyName()>What's my name?</button>
  <br><br>
  <a href="index.html">Return</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this onclick="whatsMyName();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

1. `alert("My name is"+" "+first+" "+last); // missing "+" before "first"`
2. `<button type="button" onclick="whatsMyName()">What's my name?</button>`

onclick="whatsMyName()"

Comment: Ah, a stupid mistake indeed, can't believe I forgot a +.  It worked without adding the quotes to the onclick, but I added them anyway.

Comment: No problem, it happens :)

Answer (score 3):

You seemed to have messed up quotes quite a bit.

Fixed that for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>What's my name?</title>
  <script>
    function whatsMyName() {
        var first = "Corey";
        var last = "LeBlanc";
        alert("My name is " + first + " " + last);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="whatsMyName();">What's my name?</button>
  <br><br>
  <a href="index.html">Return</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be ..

```
<button type="button" onclick="whatsMyName()">What's my name?</button>
```

also  `alert("My name is"+" "+first+" "+last)`;

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

Change:
`<button type="button" onclick=whatsMyName()>What's my name?</button>`

To:
`<button type="button" onclick="whatsMyName()">What's my name?</button>`

Change:
`alert("My name is"+" "first+" "+last);`

To:
`alert("My name is"+" "+first+" "+last);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write function in  ".."  and also change alert..as below

```
alert("My name is" + " " +first+ " " +last); 

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick = "whatsMyName()">What's my name?</button>
  <br><br>
  <a href="index.html">Return</a>
</body>
```